# saving JSON Data into MySQL Using PHP

Tags: php, json

Im getting json data from another server and need thouse data to be saved on mysql.I tryed this code but theres a problem
 when i run this code i get :  Illegal string offset for each VALUES.
I hope I made things clear if there's anything I didn't explain  please do tell.

```
    <?php
       require('db.php');
      $url = 'xxxxx';
        $data =json_encode(array('xxx' => 'xxxx',
            'xxxx' => 'xxxxx',
            'xxxx' =>'xxxx',
            'xxxx' =>'xxxx',
               'xxxx' =>'xxxx')
   );


   $options = array(
   'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => $data
  )  
   );
    $context= stream_context_create($options);
   $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  if ($result === FALSE) { }

   echo $result ;

  foreach ((array)$result as $row) {
   $table="INSERT INTO table_name(xxx,xxx,xx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx,xxxx,xxx) 
    VALUES('".$row["xxxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxxx"]."')";
   if ($conn->query($table ) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record added Successfully<br>";
   }
   else
  {
   echo "Error: " . $insert_value . "<br>" . $con->error;
 }
 }

  ?>
```

Comment: You are casting the string returned by file_get_contents into an array here, but that does not have the effect you think it does. What you are looping over now is an array with _one_ single entry, and that entry is still the original string. This is missing a json_decode or something.

Comment: Its been like 3 mouthns since i started codding and i dont know that much most of code i got it from the internet and i do not understand all of it, if u could give a hand with this i would realy apriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be `else` statement as well with `if` conditions, in case there are results. And the results should be parsed in `else`.

The code should be :

```
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "Error in fetching records.";
} else {
    echo $result;
    $rows = (array) $result;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $table = "INSERT INTO table_name(xxx,xxx,xx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx,xxxx,xxx) 
    VALUES('" . $row["xxxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxx"] . "','" . $row["xxxx"] . "')";
        if ($conn->query($table) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record added Successfully<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $insert_value . "<br>" . $con->error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i asked something  else even without the else statement the code works just fine.

Comment: It works well if there is some data in `$result` variable, otherwise you are getting errors, mentioned above. This is way to solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe i wasnt clear inuff my error is in VALUES('".$row["xxxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxx"]."','".$row["xxxx"]."')";

Comment: I did fix the way u said but still no change

Comment: What's the values contains in `$result`?

Comment: {"result":true,"message":"xxx" ,"dictCount":"x" , "guID":"xx ", "amount":"xxx" , "customerCode":"xxx" , "userName":"xxxx" , "nameSurname":"xxx" , "date":"xxx" , "dealerCode":"xxx" , "millionWarn":"false" }

Comment: Are you retrieving values as `$row["message"]` or `$row["guID"]` instead of `$row["xxxx"]`?

Comment: Yes thats the way im doing it.

Comment: Checkout I've made a minor change.

Comment: Nothing changed